# Adding more elements to listview "overwrites" the current listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

So I'm making an app that records sound and then adds recorded sounds to a listview in another activity. This is how it works:

After I record a sound, a dialog pops up asking to name the file. After I enter a certain name, I press 'Enter' and the next activity opens.

The next activity's xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".RecordedLibrary"
android:id="@+id/rLayout" >

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
  android:id="@+id/mainListView">  
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Library is empty"
    android:textColor="#C0C0C0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The next activity's java code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow);
listAdapter.add(filename.toString());
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

So, as soon as the next activity opens, I insert the filename to listAdapter. By the way, filename is the name of the file that I typed earlier in the dialog box.

R.layout.simplerow xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:padding="10dp"  
android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

So, after I record the first file and set a certain name, this happens:
http://shrani.si/f/1F/3G/4QX53vyH/1.png

And now after I record the second file and set a different name, this happens:
http://shrani.si/f/q/qH/2Jmg2zoH/screenshot2013-08-06-00-.png

As you can see, instead of adding a new row of listview, it overwrites the first row of the listview.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this with ArrayList. Something like this.

Declare a global variable:

```
ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add filename to fileNames each time the method is executed like this:

```
fileNames.add(filename.toString());
```

Then add this ArrayList to the listadapter

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, fileNames);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes! It works now. I could've probably also done it by declaring ArrayAdapter global, but this works too. Thank you!